# Can I install a firmware from a different country on my phone

Tags: sony-xperia, device-firmware, customization

As I wrote in the title I was wondering if it's possible to install a firmware from a different country on my Sony Xperia Z5 .
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find the correct firmware (created for another country but for the same device) yes, you can.
I made it several times with a Samsung S4 mini.

Take in mind that due to country regulations, the firmware may be limited in some ways (lower wifi potence, max volume limited, etc...).